# Regex for XML blocks

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Sorry for the blunt question, need some quick tips on how to pattern match a block in an xml doc.

The xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NameSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__Service</application>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__ServiceConsole</application>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_AddCampaignMembersController</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_CampaignLogicRedirectClassTestClass</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_CampaignLogicUtilitiesTestClass</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_CampaignPropertyTriggerHelper</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_ConvertEnquiryController</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APAC_CreateSpaceAssController</apexClass>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
</NameSet>
```

i want to match this block

```
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>APAC_CampaignLogicUtilitiesTestClass</apexClass>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

So as it manipulate the xml doc. via sed and remove this block. Currently i can do this,

```
find . -name *.xml | xargs sed -ri 's/<.*?>APAC_CampaignLogicUtilitiesTestClass<.*?>//g'
```

but this only removes the line

```
<apexClass>APAC_CampaignLogicUtilitiesTestClass</apexClass>
```

And not the block. What will the regex to match this entire block and use in my sed command?

Comment: [Stop trying to parse XML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576) and use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Use an XML parser. [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is one: Once you fix your xml, you can do

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//_:classAccesses[_:apexClass = "APAC_CampaignLogicUtilitiesTestClass"]' file.xml
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. But what were you meaning when you said, "Once you fix your xml"?

Comment: `NameSet` has no opening tag. Look at the 2nd line of the XML you posted

Comment: Thanks again for pointing that out. i have corrected it. I messed that up while replacing the actual word in there. Btw, what is the pattern used here? where can i read more on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain well : the XML has an xmlns attribute but no specified prefix. xmlstarlet uses underscore as the default prefix